# How to export LogisticRegressionCV model and implement on flutter

Tags: python, flutter, logistic-regression

I have followed this code ([Cat_Vs_Dog_Image_Classification_ML](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jtVvbwpaQO7TiMCUxVuIIR8YSzc-Tg7X#scrollTo=NHbh5EXJpiLt)) as a classification using logisticRegressionCv But I don't know a way to export the model. What do I have to do And after i got the model, how can i implement it on flutter? Please help me if you know.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of storing a Machine learning Model.
The very optimal way is using pickle.

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(curr_model_name,'name_i_store_with.pkl')
```

You can load it using

```
my_model=pickle.load('name_i_store_with.pkl')
```

You can use joblib also( just replace pickle with joblib above)

Hope , [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saving-a-machine-learning-model/)  might help you better.